# How to use weird characters in VSCode keybindings

Tags: visual-studio-code, key-bindings, scancodes

I'd like to create a keybind using AltGr + f, or maybe a keybind with the result of this 2 together (đ), I tried using scan codes already, but they don't seem to work as a key, how can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

AltGr + f should be possible to assign, but keep in my such key stroke assignments are based on base keyboard codes, for an english keyboard. They cannot use keyboard mappings for a language. This in turn means you should stay away from using shortcuts that involve language specific letters or even custom keypositions (keyboards for languages other than english sometimes have keys in different places, reachable with different modifier combinations).